# Find the closest prime number of a character's ASCII value --- Python

Tags: python, ascii

I get a string input from user, breaking it up into a character list, converting each character into its ASCII value and then searching for the nearest Prime Number. Convert the (prime number) ASCII value back into a list of characters, join it together and print it on the screen. Sounds pretty simple but I find it tricky trying to find the nearest prime number.

```
def is_prime(num):
    if num > 1:
        for n in range(2, num):
            if (num % n) == 0:
                return False
        else:
            return True
    else:
        return False


test_cases = int(input())


for _ in range(test_cases):
    string = str(input())
    array = list(string)
    result_array = []

    for i in array:
        if is_prime(ord(i)):
            result_array.append(i)
        else:
            pass

    print("".join(result_array))
```

On the last line the "pass" statement is just to have an error-free code till I find the solution. That's the part where the searching goes on.

Comment: classical mistake: don't loop till the number itself: `for n in range(2, num)` but to `for n in range(2, int(num**0.5+1))` you'll save iterations.

Comment: what you need is to generate the list of the prime numbers from 32 to 127 and use `bisect` to see which is the closest one. the code you provided does nothing close to that.

Comment: Thanks! Just on time... Was on google searching for a more efficient way to find if a number is prime or not.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You don't need to generate the list, you can hard code it. Only 31 prime numbers are <= 128

Comment: @Gribouillis let's settle on "generate a hardcoded list then" :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The algorithm to generate this hard coded list is by googling.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre what you say can be implemented in the last "else" section.. I just remove the pass and type in the stuff.. My problem, is to search the nearest number... Could you explain "bisect" a bit more? Python documentation goes around the answer but never answers it

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Your code, finds the nearest ascii value above the current number... Input: AFREEN should have the output CGSCCO but instead gives CGSGGO

Comment: issue fixed, and very short answer variation added (thanks for your patience, tuning the indices was not that trivial)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre how could it be done in order to include lower case letters also..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm cannot work because it never tackles with the "closest to a prime" issue (note that checking a prime like that is not efficient: the max boundary can be `n**0.5+1`)

That said, there's a flaw in this problem for lower-case letters:

prime numbers skip from 113 to 127. For a high lowercase letter, the closest prime is 127, which isn't printable.

So I'll stick to uppercase letters (unless we want to print the closest *lowest* prime, in which case lowercase is OK)

What I would do is:

- generate/copy the list of primes from 0 to 97 (ASCII for `Z` is 96)
- loop on the characters, and use `bisect` module to find the insertion position of the character ASCII code in the prime list (which must be *sorted* for `bisect` to work properly).
- Then check if upper bound is closer than lower bound, and choose the index of the prime list.
- Fiddle (a lot) with the insertion indices to avoid errors (like in my first version of the post)
- Add to list. `join` in the end

code:

```
import bisect

# list sampled from https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/1000.txt
# ASCII code for 'A' is 65, no need to go lower
primes = [int(x) for x in """61 67     71     73     79     83     89     97""".split()]

word = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ"

primeword = []
for w in word:
    ow = ord(w)
    i = bisect.bisect_left(primes,ow)
    delta1 = abs(ow-primes[i])
    delta2 = abs(ow-primes[i-1])
    # select this index or next index (no risk for out of range here)
    primeword.append(chr(primes[i + int(delta2 > delta1) - 1]))

print("".join(primeword))
```

which gives me:

```
CCCCCGGGIIIIOOOOSSSSSYYYY
```

EDIT: since we generated the prime numbers, we could as well directly generate the lookup table for the characters and use `str.translate`:

```
primeword_dict = {65: 'C', 66: 'C', 67: 'C', 68: 'C', 69: 'C', 70: 'G', 71: 'G', 72: 'G', 73: 'I', 74: 'I', 75: 'I', 76: 'I', 77: 'O', 78: 'O', 79: 'O', 80: 'O', 82: 'S', 83: 'S', 84: 'S', 85: 'S', 86: 'S', 87: 'Y', 88: 'Y', 89: 'Y', 90: 'Y'}
print(word.translate(primeword_dict))
```

that would be even faster & shorter, and allows to pass strings like `"HELLO  WORLD.` (with spaces & punctuation in it) and only have the letters changed & other symbols kept intact.